# OS X Lion auto-brightness offset

Tags: macbook-pro, osx-lion, display-settings

I'm noticing the display brightness auto-adjust in Lion seems to be less sensitive to light (more likely to dim the display) than on Snow Leopard running on the same hardware.

Is there a simple way to keep auto-adjust enabled, but change the neutral brightness offset so I don't have to keep turning it up all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I figured it out.

1. Uncheck 'Automatically adjust brightness'.
2. Set up desired brightness for current ambient light amount.
3. Check 'Automatically adjust brightness' again.

Now it will adjust brightness properly.